# Ember.js binding to and saving belongsTo property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models related to one another via `belongsTo` (a reciprocal relationship, i.e. 1:1) utilizing the `async` property. Having retrieved one record and setting it to the Model on the router, I have access to the properties in the main record and its associate—everything works fine there. I've used input helpers to bind properties to `input` and `textarea` elements so that users can make changes to the model, including properties on the associated record. However when I run my `save()` function, Ember only makes a `PUT` request for the main record, not for the associated one, even though it's the one that changed.

**Entry.js (Model)**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  // Properties
  entry: DS.attr('Number'),
  ...

  // Relational properties
  definition: DS.belongsTo('definition', {async: true}),
 ...
});
```

**Definition.js (Model)**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  // Properties
  blocks: DS.attr(),
  ...
  // Relational properties
  entry: DS.belongsTo('entry', {async: true}),
  ...
});
```

**Route.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('Entry', params.entry_id);
  },
  actions: {
    saveDef: function(){
      // console.log('Saving . . .');
      var entry = this.controller.get('content');
      entry.save().then(function(){
        // console.log('Saved Success');
      }, function(err){
        // console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing a relationship doesn't set the dirty flag on a model. This is a known bug. However, the save call should trigger a network request. Is it not being triggered? Check the network tab in Chrome Inspector.

Comment: By 'changing a relationship' do you mean 'changing a property on a related record'? I'm not actually changing the relationship, to be clear. As far as the network request goes, the `save` function triggers a network request, but only for the main model (entry; a `PUT` request to `.../entries/:id`), but nothing for the definitions API endpoint. I imagine that if the record were embedded, then it would be OK, but it's not.

Comment: Also, I updated the question to more accurately present my question.

Comment: You're correct. If you're changing a property of the other record (definition), you need to save that particular one.

Comment: In other words, `this.controller.get('content.definition').save();`

Comment: Using embedded records can be a solution. The other solution would be to trigger two saves, but then you'll have to deal with consistency issues like one of them being saved while the other is not. I suggest using embedded records if possible.

Comment: `this.controller.get('content.definition').save();` was my first thought, too. But I get a `.save() is not a function` error whenever I try it.

Comment: The reason could be because there is no linked definition. You should check for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember when you save a model other models don't get saved.
You need to save each model by itself. I suggest you create a separate view for each model and save it individually because you might run into consistency issues.

Anyway, here's how you'd save both models.

```
var model = this.controller.get('content');
model.save();
var definition = model.get('definition');
if( definition && definition.then ) {
  definition.then(function(definition) { definition.save(); });
} else if( definition ) {
  definition.save();
}
```

**Update:**

The issue here is definition is not loaded. So when you call `model.get('definition')` Ember will need to fetch the model from the server. This is why it returns a promise.

It seems to me that you're trying to save the definition model just to update the relationship. You don't need to do that. The first save is enough. Updating the other model should be done on the server.

Comment: I'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: definition.save is not a function`

Comment: That's wierd. It could be due to the fact that the relationship is async. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Can you add your template as well?

Comment: That did it. Would you mind explaining what exactly this additional code is doing—I see it has something to do with promises, but It's still a bit enigmatic to me.

Comment: Great. So, supposing I just want to save the definition model, I could just do `this.controller.get('content.definition').then(function(def){ def.save(); } );` ? It seems to work. The `if` statement is there just to use the promise `.then` syntax for async records, while the `elseif` executes the `save` function otherwise (assuming it's not `null`); is this right?

Answer (score 1):

*first of all you have to save first model the set the returning data to second model the save second model*

**Route.js**

```js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('Entry', params.entry_id);
  },
  actions: {
    saveDef: function(){
      // console.log('Saving . . .');
      var def=this.controllerFor("deffinition").get("content"); // cotroller of defeinition route
      var entry = this.controller.get('content'); // controller of entry route
      def.save().then(function(res){
        // console.log('Saved Success');
        let def = _this.store.peekRecord('Definition', res.get('id'));
        entry.set('deffinition', def);
        entry.save().then(function (res) {
         // Success callback
            
        });
      }, function(err){
        // console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[WORKING WITH RELATIONSHIPS](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/models/working-with-relationships/)

Answer (score 0):

Ember does not do cascading save to your models, you'll need to save that other model your self.